# How to select the data correspondent to the nearest time to certain hour?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a series of data with certain timestamps. I want to make a query that gets the data corresponding to the nearest measure to 6:00 (t<6:00) every day within a month.

I have tried to do it in several ways but none of them have gave me the exact result that I wanted. It doesn't ocur to me how to perform this query :(

What I tried at the moment didn't seem to work. I tried to perform nested selects to get a list of the valid times, but I can't make out the logic of it

```
SELECT Measure, Time FROM Table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Time) = 5
AND TIME IN(SELECT Time FROM Table)
```

At the end I tried`EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Time) = 5 and EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM Time) = 59` because in my particular case it kind of works, but I prefer to achieve the proper solution.

Let's say that I have a lot of measures with non regular timestamps. What my query should give me is 30 rows (well it depends on the month) having the neares timestamp to 6:00 each day from behind.

Thanks for anticipated.

Comment: We could provide a useful query if you presented at least some of the schema:  table name and relevant field names.

Comment: Lets say that I have a table with measures about the temperature of a room and the correspondent timestamps. Then I want to retrieve the temperature with the timestamp nearest to 6:00 for every day, so about 30 rows.

SELECT Temperature, Timestamp FROM Table
WHERE  MAX(Timestamp < 6:00) for each day

Comment: [Why I would downvote](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) this question if you were not the new to SO. I most likely will next time if you will not update your question

Comment: Sorry, I did attempt to solve this problem, in fact I was dealing with it all the day, I will try to update the question to prove that

Comment: @PabloSánchezGonzález It's a good idea to edit additional details like that into your question rather than leaving them in a comment. You might also want to add what you have tried already and how the results differed from what you want. (referring to your first comment btw)

Comment: You should provide [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can focus on helping you vs. reverse engineering you data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of one way to solve the problem.  I have used MySQL since you didn't originally specify the database.  Most SQLs have similar functions to work with dates and times, but some might need slight revision.

To create the test database:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
USE `test`;

DROP TABLE if exists `samples`;

CREATE TABLE if not exists `samples` (
        `id`     int not null auto_increment,
        `measure`       float null,
        `tstamp`        timestamp,
        primary key (`id`)
        )
ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT `samples` (measure, tstamp) VALUES
        (4.79,  '2019-06-04 05:59:24'),
        (6.80,  '2019-06-04 05:59:46'),
        (6.13,  '2019-06-04 06:00:19'),
        (8.18,  '2019-06-04 06:01:22'),
        (6.78,  '2019-06-04 06:01:15'),

        (3.79,  '2019-06-03 08:00:00'),
        (6.18,  '2019-06-03 07:00:00'),
        (4.78,  '2019-06-03 06:00:00'),
        (4.80,  '2019-06-03 05:00:00'),
        (4.13,  '2019-06-03 04:00:00');
```

Verify:

```
mysql> select * from samples;
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | measure | tstamp              |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |    4.79 | 2019-06-04 05:59:24 |
|  2 |     6.8 | 2019-06-04 05:59:46 |
|  3 |    6.13 | 2019-06-04 06:00:19 |
|  4 |    8.18 | 2019-06-04 06:01:22 |
|  5 |    6.78 | 2019-06-04 06:01:15 |
|  6 |    3.79 | 2019-06-03 08:00:00 |
|  7 |    6.18 | 2019-06-03 07:00:00 |
|  8 |    4.78 | 2019-06-03 06:00:00 |
|  9 |     4.8 | 2019-06-03 05:00:00 |
| 10 |    4.13 | 2019-06-03 04:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is a query to list the data for the sample closest to 06:00 of June 3:

```
USE test;
SELECT  measure,
        tstamp,
        abs(time_to_sec (time(tstamp)) - time_to_sec('6:00:00')) AS delta
FROM samples
WHERE tstamp BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-04'
ORDER BY delta
LIMIT 1;
```

Same query except selecting June 4:

```
SELECT  measure,
        tstamp,
        abs(time_to_sec (time(tstamp)) - time_to_sec('6:00:00')) AS delta
FROM samples
WHERE tstamp BETWEEN '2019-06-04' AND '2019-06-05'
ORDER BY delta
LIMIT 1;
```

Results:

```
Database changed
+---------+---------------------+-------+
| measure | tstamp              | delta |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
|    4.78 | 2019-06-03 06:00:00 |     0 |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------+---------------------+-------+
| measure | tstamp              | delta |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
|     6.8 | 2019-06-04 05:59:46 |    14 |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```